# Can I combine Cron special string "@reboot" with regular scheduling?

Tags: cron

In the Cron manpage it mentions the special string "@reboot".  Can I combine this with a regular schedule?  The goal is simply to schedule a job to run once a day AND immediately in the event of a system reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, although you'll need to enter it as two cron jobs.

```
@reboot /do/something
10 0 * * * /do/something
```

Comment: thanks, I am aware of that option. Just wondering if there's a way to combine them for the sake of eliminating redundant entries

Comment: No, there's no syntax that I'm aware of to combine the two types into one rule.

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case you will have to write down the same cron job twice.